# How to erase an element of a vector and check for a condition on other elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, vector

How do I erase an element one by one in a `vector`? I want to check the vector using some conditions after a specific element is removed.

I tried it in this way, but it doesn't work. What's wrong? `v is already initialized`

```
        long long max = maxSubArraySum(v);
        long long t = 0;

        for(long long i = 0; i < n ; i++){
            std::vector<long long> cv;
            cv = v;
            //cout << "i = " << i << "v = " <<v[i] << '\n'; 
            cv.erase(find(cv.begin(),cv.end(),v[i])); // <—- wrong
            // EDIT 
            // cv.erase(cv.begin()+i); <—- fix.
            t = maxSubArraySum(cv); 
            //cout << "t = " <<  t << '\n';
            if(t > max){
                max = t;
                //cout << max << '\n';
            }
        }
        // cout << max << '\n';
     }

}
```

For example, `v = {1, -2 , 3, -2 ,5 }`,

- I remove first `1`, then `maxSubArraySum` will be for `cv = {-2,3,-2,5 }` which is `6 for this subarray {3,-2,5}`.
- Next I remove `-2`, then `maxSubArraySum` will be for `cv = {1, 3,-2,5}` which is `6 for this subarray {3,-2,5}`
- Next I remove `3`, then `maxSubArraySum` will be for `cv = {1, -2,-2,5}` which is `-2 for this subarray {-2,5}`
- Next I remove `-2`, then `maxSubArraySum` will be for `cv = {1, -2, 3, 5}` which is `8 for this subarray {3,5}`
- Next I remove `5`, then `maxSubArraySum` will be for `cv = {1, -2,3,-2}` which is `4 for this subarray {1,-2,3}`

How do I code it in `C++`?

EDIT : 
I got the answer. 
My code is was slightly off as it was deleting the first element `find` found. In case of duplicates, this showed the error. 
So I changed it to delete indexes only.
Thank you.

Comment: Expanding on @LogicStuff , `cv` is a temporary copy of `v`. You modify the copy, then it is discarded and created again from the unaltered original `v`. You're going to need to provide more code to properly answer why you can't directly erase from `v`. I assume you have a reason, and you know what they say about assume... What? You don't know what they say?  Damn assumptions.

Comment: If I don't copy `v` to `cv`, I keep losing elements one by one when I erase them. I need to erase an element in index `1`, find `maxSum`, then again from the initial `vector` erase the element in index `2` and so on.

Comment: Like I said, I assume you have a reason. I assume it's a good one. But I don't **know** the reason and can't make good suggestions on how to get you out of the problem you've found yourself in. @Shreevardhan 's answer makes perfectly good sense in the context of your posted code. You won't get a better answer than that without more context and more code so we can see why you get that segfault from doing something that should work.

Comment: @sudoankit  You do not need to erase anything from the vector.  Just swap the last element in a loop with the current element you want to "erase" and process the vector up until the last item as the subarray.  Please [look here](http://ideone.com/pErMv4) at the items that are processed on each iteration of the loop.  The only thing not in the code at the link is the calculation of the max items.  If you want to create a temp vector from the iterators, you can do that in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use find. Try this:

```
     cv.erase(cv.begin()+i);
```

This will find the element at the ith position and delete it, using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: The problem is `cv` is a temporary copy of `v`. OP is erasing from the wrong `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the vector `cv` before the for loop (outside) and your problem will be solved. To simplify, use the `v` directly instead of making a copy

```
while (!v.empty()) {
    v.erase(v.begin());
    cout << endl;
    long long t = maxSubArraySum(v);
    if (t > max) {
        max = t;
        // cout << max << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me `Segmentation fault: 11`.

Comment: @sudoankit If `v` has at least `n` elements, this should not give seg fault. You can use a debugger to see where exactly you get that.